# Converting strings to int/float if user input is valid

Tags: python

Hi I am curious if there is a way to convert user input to an specific variable type based off the content of the input (I'm using raw_input(), not sure if there's a better function for this). I know raw_input() always makes a string, but can said string be converted to an integer or a floating point if the input is valid? For example, if the user enters '1,' is there a way to have that variable stored as an integer rather than a string? Here is the code I am attempting to make work:

```
print "Subtraction Calculator (x-y)"

def calculator(x, y):
  if [isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float)] and [isinstance(y, int) or 
isinstance(y, float)]: #This should be checking to see if x and y are both
numerical
  D = x - y 
  return D
 else:
  return "One or more inputs is not a number."

x = raw_input("x = ")
y = raw_input("y = ")

print calculator(x, y)
```

Obviously this code doesn't work as x and y are both strings due to raw_input(), but I don't seem to be getting the proper error message ("One or more inputs is not a number.") and am instead getting an error at (D = x - y). I believe that this is due to my 'if' statement always registering as True, but I am not sure why this is either.

Comment: you can change string to int by use of int() method like 
x= int(raw_input("x = "))

Comment: `[isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float)]` is a non-empty list and thus true.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using exception handling. Basically, the idea is simply try to convert `x` and `y` into floats and do the calculation you want. If `x` or `y` are not able to be converted to floats, python will raise a `ValueError` which you can catch in a try and except statement. You could make a loop so that you keep asking the user to input `x` and `y` until it works like so:

```
    while(True):
        try:
            x = raw_input('x = ')
            y = raw_input('y = ')
            print(float(x)-float(y))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('One of those was not a float! Try again!')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about simply returning the result that you want and if one of the two cannot be converted to a number, it will raise a `ValueError`:

```
def calculator(x, y):
    return float(x) - float(y)

x = raw_input("x = ")
y = raw_input("y = ")

print calculator(x, y)
```

Note that if you do want to check if a variable is either an int or float you can use `isinstance(x, (int, float))`. Therefore, your code can be rewritten as:

```
def calculator(x, y):
    if isinstance(x, (int, float)) and isinstance(y, (int, float)):
        return x - y
    return "One or more inputs is not a number."
```